# How to find a word inside bracket in string and replace it with new data

Tags: c#

I have some string like this :

> this is some [string,10] and i want to replace it with [anotherstring,10]

i want find **[string,10]** and **[anotherstring,10]** and replace it with new data.

how can i do this?

Comment: Any word inside brackets or just a single word followed by ,10

Comment: Is the ,10 important?

Comment: any word. i must get some data depend on that word inside bracket from database.

Comment: @TimS.  its important.

Comment: do you want the output to look like "my string is anotherstring" or "my string is [anotherstring,10]"? I suggest you update your question to clarify these issues

Comment: i want my output be like this **this is some data and i want to replace it with MyNewDataI... .**

Comment: this 10 is for substring my data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example [regex replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx), using a [`MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) to do something complicated with the result:

```
Regex.Replace(
"this is some [string,10] and i want to replace it with [anotherstring,10]",
@"\[(.*?),(\d+)\]",
m => "[was " + m.Groups[1].ToString() + "::" + int.Parse(m.Groups[2].ToString()) + "]")
```

It captures the string and number separately, so you can do things with them individually. If instead you only need it to be `,10`, you can do a `@"\[(.*?),10\]"` pattern. Or if you want any characters inside it treated as one value, `@"\[(.*?)\]"` As shown, it results in:

> this is some [was string::10] and i want to replace it with [was
>   anotherstring::10]

Comment: thanks that work. is there any way to get list of my brackets?

Comment: `Regex.Matches("this is some [string,10] and i want to replace it with [anotherstring,10]", @"\[(.*?),(\d+)\]")`